# Meteor + React : Server side routes?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, server, iron-router, flow-router

I am buidling a meteor app with react. I am using these two packages for a clientside router. [kadira:flow-router](https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/flow-router) & [kadira:react-layout](https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/react-layout)
But I just realized I have to respond to a post request from paypal. Since this would not be rendering anything this would require a server side route.

How can i answer to a server side route while using a client side router?
Don't tell me I have to build the routing system again.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `meteorhacks:picker`?  This should do what you're looking for.  Here's a link to a [tutorial](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/server-side-routing-with-picker/) on The Meteor Chef.

Comment: Oh i'll check that out now!

Comment: That worked but i can't get to the body of the request with picker. It's just telling me Function: parser onBody @StephenWoods

Comment: oh wait no your link had the answer to that too. Good job!

Comment: Do i keep using react-mounter? or what do I have to use to get picker to work with react?